# Неожиданные значения в арифметики

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

0.030000000000001137 - 0.03 === 1.1379786002407855e-15
Как этого избежать? Использовать int, uint я не могу, мне нужно много знаков после запятой.

```
private function stage_enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    var currentTime:Number = getTimer()* 0.001;
    var elapsedTime:Number = (currentTime-_lastTime) 
    _lastTime = currentTime;

    var isMind:Boolean = _timeInMind > 0;
    var isCanAdd:Boolean = _addMindTime > elapsedTime;

    var timeStep:Number =0;
    if (elapsedTime < _maxDelay)
    {
        timeStep = elapsedTime;
        if (isMind && isCanAdd)
        {
            var n:Number = _addedTime > _timeInMind ? _timeInMind : _addedTime;
            timeStep += n;
            _timeInMind -= _addedTime;
            if (_timeInMind < 0)
            {
                _timeInMind = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timeStep = _maxDelay;
        _timeInMind += (elapsedTime - _maxDelay);
        trace( 'test',_timeInMind,elapsedTime-_maxDelay,elapsedTime,_maxDelay);
    }
    this.time(timeStep)
}
```

Вот эта строчка ошибку выдаёт, прибавляется 1.5

```
_timeInMind += (elapsedTime - _maxDelay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вам выводить куда то надо.

Можно указать кол-во знаков требуемое для exponential notation.

```
var n:Number = 0.030000000000001137 - 0.03;
trace( n.toPrecision(21) ); // 0.00000000000000113797860024078545393
```

Comment: Мне не выводить надо, а проводить дальнейшие расчёты. А это становится невозможным, так как результат "не пойми какой".

Comment: И даже у Вас результат не правильный, откуда эти цифры взялись?

Comment: на результат вычислений это никак не влияет, с фиксированной запятой и мантисой (е-15) только на выводе
возможно вы не понимаете что это за запись числа
это 1,1379786002407855 в степени -15
без мантисы, в обычной нотации это абсолютно то же число - 0.00000000000000113797860024078545393

Comment: Вы правы, я не понимал, что это такое. А Вы не знаете как это можно исправить?
Мне вот эта запись даёт отрицательное число, хотя его не может быть не как.

Comment: результат ошибочный возможно потому что вывод на пределе точности
внутренние вычисления вряд ли с ошибкой

Comment: С ошибкой! Вместо 0.000000000000001137 получается полторы секунды. Разница просто убийственная. Её визуально видно.

Comment: Я не понимаю что там происходит в коде. Кусок кода покажите.